# VkNet, c# Как авторизваться без приложения?

Tags: c#, python, vkontakte-api, vknet

К примеру на питоне с помощью библиотеки vk_api, можно авторизваться зная только login и пароль.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import vk_api, requests
session = requests.Session()
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
try:
    vk_session.auth()
except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
    print(error_msg)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```

как сделать такое же, но только с помощью VkNet'а ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим документацию по вашей vk_api и видим:

> Для авторизации в ВК используется симуляция действий пользователя

и

> Чтобы не авторизовываться каждый раз при запуске скрипта сохраняются cookies и access_token

То есть уже видно, что там идет работа с какой то эмуляцией. Идем дальше, смотрим код (я в питоне не силен, но все же, понять куда и как идут запросы можно). Смотрим кусок кода, который отвечает за авторизацию: [примерно этот](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/vk_api/vk_api.py#L213).

Что видим? А видим мы то, что этот `vk_api` эмулирует запросы, которые отправляет браузер при обычной авторизации и работает с куками. Дальше не вникал, может где и получает сам токен, но изначально авторизация там совсем не стандартная (если брать API авторизацию...).

В общем, хотите также - переписывайте авторизацию на c#, либо сами отлавливайте запросы и шлите их на C# как вашей душе захочется. Не хотите мучаться, используйте стандартные методы получения токена.

Про авторизацию в VK API можно почитать в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/access_token).